# K9-Mail keep email open

Tags: k9-mail

When switching back to k9 mail using the app-icon on the homescreen, a previously displayed email is going to be closed and the list of emails is going to be displayed instead. This doesn't happen when using the 'Last-App'-function.

As I don't have the 'Last-App'-button in my bottom bar I don't use it in my workflow (tbh, I prefer it like this anyway).

How can I stop emails from being closed when opening the app from the homescreen?